# Reorganize music library with Picard or another program

Tags: metadata, picard

I want to rename/reorganize my music library for easy reading off a LCD screen, on my CDJs and on my car stereo

this is the goal, this is not a functional script. my script attempt is doing it:
`%albumartist% || VA - %albumname% / %tracknumber% %trackname%`

I've tried with MusicBrainz Picard, but have not achieved the right script yet. Can anyone recommend a Picard script, or a different program/script? thanks so much

this is basically the default Picard script

```
$if2(%albumartist%,%artist%,VA) - 
$if(%albumartist%,%album%/,)
$if($gt(%totaldiscs%,1),$if($gt(%totaldiscs%,9),$num(%discnumber%,2),%discnumber%)-,)$if($and(%albumartist%,%tracknumber%),$num(%tracknumber%,2) ,)$if(%_multiartist%,%artist% - ,)%title%
```